# CSS Grid: Column with two images should have the height of the first column

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6kufq548/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200"/>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="right--first">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="right--second">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

I want to achieve, that the images in the second column together (!) have the same height as the image in the first column. Later, all images are coming from a database and have the same dimensions, that's why I used fixed and equal sizes here. Despite of this, the height of `.right` should never be higher than the height of `.left`.

How can I achieve this with Grid? Or do I need to switch to flex?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know - the solution in your link is based on flex. I wonder if I can solve it with grid...

Comment: Grid works the same way.